# How to catch a bitmap from TcxTabSheet in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Hello I have PageControl which generates TabSheets when open a new PDF or Image. I want to catch a bitmap from tabsheet and show it in dxImageListBox. I open multiple files in multiple TabSheets I want all tabsheets  to be captured.
I need procedure which catch screen only on tabsheet control is that possible?
I have this function but it doesnt work

```
  Function TPAMailJournalScan.CreateBitmapFromTabSheet(Tabsheet2: TdlcxTabSheet) : TBitmap;
VAR
  Bitmap:  TBitmap;
BEGIN
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  TRY
    Bitmap.Width  := Tabsheet2.Width;
    Bitmap.Height := Tabsheet2.Height;

    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;    // avoid palettes

    Bitmap.Canvas.Lock;
    TRY

      // What Windows message paints this area?
      Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clActiveBorder;
      Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);

      Tabsheet2.Perform(WM_PAINT, Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0)
    FINALLY
      Bitmap.Canvas.Unlock
    END;

    Result := Bitmap;
  FINALLY
    Bitmap.Free
  END ;
END;
```

I catch this images with this code :

```
 for I := 0 to pgcScan.PageCount -1 do
  begin
    pgcScan.Pages[I].Show;
    FImage := CreateBitmapFromTabSheet(TdlcxTabSheet(pgcScan.Pages[I]));
    imlScans.Add(FImage,FImage);
    lbImages.ImageList := imlScans;
    lbImages.AddItem(IntToStr(I),I);
  end;
```

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to use to your question.  Also, are you trying to display a PDF file as an image on a tabsheet, or trying to save as a PDF file an image which is displayed on a tabsheet, or what?

Comment: Pdf files are loaded into AdobePdf plugin

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question.  Are the PDF files displayed by the plugin inside your application or not?  If we can't understand your q, we can't answer it.

Comment: Pdf files are displayed into a Pdf plugin inside a pagecontrol which creates tabsheet. Tabsheet is a container of a pdf viewer

Comment: So, are you displaying the PDF by doing something like calling OpenInWindowEx on an Acrobat CAcroAVDoc object using the window handle of your tabsheet?  The reason I'm asking about this is that if you're using the Acrobat automation library like this, you may not need to "capture" the images at all.  I will explain once you've answered.  The -1 isn't mine, btw, but evidently someone else may be having difficulty understanding exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will display a PDF file on a tabsheet using Acrobat COM objects
from Acrobat_TLB.Pas and copy the PDF's image from the tabsheet to a TImage on
the form.  Adding the image (or a thumbnail of it) to a TdxImageListBox is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
TPdfViewer = class(TForm)
[...]
  Page : CAcroPDPage;
  AcroApp : CAcroApp;
  PDDoc : CAcroPDDoc;
  ARect : CAcroRect;
  FileName : String;
  Captured : Boolean;
end;

procedure TPdfViewer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileName := 'd:\aaad7\pdf\F1.Pdf';

  AcroApp := CoAcroApp.Create; 

  //  We need to "lock" the AcroApp object before we can get
  //  Acrobat to draw a PDF on one of our app's components (see
  //  the DrawPDF method below)

  AcroApp.Lock('MyLock');

  PDDoc := CoAcroPDDoc.Create;
  ARect := CoCAcroRect.Create;
end;

procedure TPdfViewer.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //  Release the "lock" applied during FormCreate
  AcroApp.Unlock;
end;

procedure TPdfViewer.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawPDF;
end;

procedure TPdfViewer.DrawPDF;
var
  OK : Boolean;
  AControl : TWinControl;
  BM : TBitmap;
begin
  AControl := TabSheet1;
  ARect.Top := 775; // value established by trial and error
  ARect.Left := 0;
  ARect.Right := AControl.Width - ARect.Left;
  ARect.Bottom := 0;

  //  First, open the PDF and get the Acrobat Page object to draw
  //  it on the tabsheet

  PDDoc.Open(FileName);

  //  The following obtains a reference to the first page of the
  //  PDF so that it can be drawn on the tabsheet

  Page := PDDoc.AcquirePage(0) as CAcroPDPage;
  OK := Page.DrawEx(AControl.Handle, 0, ARect, 0, 0, 100);

  if not Captured then begin
    //  If this is the first time the PDF has been drawn,
    // copy it to a TImage via a temporary TBitMap
    BM := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      BM.Width := AControl.ClientWidth;
      BM.Height := AControl.ClientHeight;
      BitBlt(BM.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, AControl.ClientWidth, AControl.ClientHeight, Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(BM);
    finally
      BM.Free;
    end;
    Captured := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I confess I couldn't get my earlier idea of saving the PDF to a JPG file to work using the Acrobat COM objects, so I've replaced that with code that displays the PDF on a tabsheet, captures it to a bitmap and copies that to a TImage on the form.  It has a few rough edges but hopefully should get you going.